# How to convert a PDF InputStream to an Html String?

Tags: java

I have a PDF InputStream which is type ByteArrayInputStream

I need convert this input to html string.

Is it possible or not?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible point to start is using [pdf2dom](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/documentation.php). Please have a look [here](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/download.php) for how to integrate the dependencies into your project and to read more about possible required dependcies.

Pdf2Dom provides a PDF parser that converts the documents to an HTML DOM representation. This DOM tree then can be serialized to an HTML file or used for further processing.

Here's a small code example, I tried it and it worked well:

```
    private void convert() {
    try {
        PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(SOURCE_PDF));
        PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree(PDFDomTreeConfig.createDefaultConfig());
        Writer output = new PrintWriter(TARGET_HTML, "UTF-8");
        parser.writeText(pdf, output);
        output.close();
        pdf.close();
    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // Handle errors
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried PDFDomTree but it says : "PDFDomTree cannot be resolved to a type" and don't recommend import class.

Comment: @Hasan Kaan TURAN PDFDomTree is part of the pdf2dom-x-x.jar (import org.fit.pdfdom.PDFDomTree). Have you properly added the jar as dependency (via your build tool or local jar)?

Comment: I solved it ;
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.cssbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdf2dom</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>